# ASP.NET files necessary for development

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I am just getting started in ASP.NET and have some existing projects to maintain.

I have read that ASP.NET projects include a folder called app_data, a code behind DLL, .sln project files, .proj files etc

Which of these files are necessary for the continued development of a ASP.NET website?

Also, are there others which are key to building ASP.NET applications?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there are two kinds of ASP.NET application: Web Sites and Web Application Projects. If you have files with a .csproj type or .vbproj, then you're in luck - you have a Web Application Project. You'll want to open the .csproj file as a project in Visual Studio. All the files that are listed are necessary.

In fact, if it's in the site's folder or subfolders, you should assume it's necessary.